# How to send a json to a java rest service with an angular $resource?

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, java-ee-6

The project I'm working on has a rest service hosted for a JavaEE application, as a POST method. I've deployed it, and tested it from SOAP Ui, using the media type selector as "application/json". I've created a resource factory to use this service, and set the default parameter in the custom action I created. However, the parameters get added as parameters onto the url string, like excess variables (i.e. api.com/query?thing:123). I'm not sure how to send my JSON in a manner that will satisfy the API.

Here's the code:

Angular resource:

```
angular.module('aumBills', ['ngResource'])

.factory('Bills', ['$resource',
    function($resource)
    {
        return $resource(
        '/ua_aumcore/api/v1/bills/:billableEventI',
        {
            billableEventI:'@billableEventI'
        },
        {
            getList: {method: 'POST', params: {'userID':'1234'}, isArray: true, url: '/ua_aumcore/api/v1/bills/query/'}
        });
    }]);
```

Java REST service:

```
@Path("bills")
public class BillableEventResource implements BillableEventService {

    @EJB
    private BillableEventBean billableEventBean;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("query")
    @Override
    public List<BillableEventDuplicate> getBillableEventDuplicateList(BillableEventQueryFilter queryFilter) {
        return billableEventBean.getBillableEventDuplicateList(queryFilter);

    }

    @GET
    //@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("{billableEventI}")
    @Override
    public BillableEventDuplicate getBillableEvent(@PathParam("billableEventI") String billID) {
        return billableEventBean.getBillableEvent(billID);

    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't completely solved it, but I did reduce one potential issue. When invoking the custom action getList, to feed it the json object it needs to be done when invoked. So, instead of feeding it {userID:1234}  there, when called it would be Bills.getList({},{userID:1234})... (or something similar, I've got the code on my as-of-now inaccessible laptop - will update when I have access again).